# Build new computer using Scripts

Tags: windows, scripting, build-automation

I would like to automate the process of setting up a new PC, this would include downloading and installing the latest windows and office updates; installing software from a network share (some software will require a restart so the script would need to be able to login and continue) adding PC to a domain and setting up local user accounts.

Is this possible and what would be the best scripting language to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/). Allows you to pre-configure many options, slipstream updates and service packs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The standard method in enterprise IT is the [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/deploy-windows-mdt/deploy-windows-10-with-the-microsoft-deployment-toolkit). Even if another OS deployment technique (SCCM, BigFix, SpecOps...) is used, the Windows images are often developed in MDT.

There is no better guide to getting started than [Johan Arwidmark's](https://deploymentresearch.com/Research) book series ["Deployment Fundamentals"](https://deploymentartist.com/Books). There is also material at [Windows Noob](https://www.windows-noob.com/forums/forum/74-microsoft-deployment-toolkit-mdt/).

You could integrate [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), [BoxStarter](https://boxstarter.org/) or [Ninite](https://ninite.com/) for app management after the OS is deployed.